# What should I add or remove on my factorial calculator code?

Tags: java, math, calculator, factorial

I'm new to coding, so I've been getting confused on what I should add or remove on my code. When I entered the factorial of 2, it also prints out the factorial 1, when I only want the factorial of 2 to print out.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FactorialCalculator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        int i, fact = 1, number;
                
        System.out.println("<------ Factorial Calculator ------>");
        System.out.print("Enter a positive integer: ");
        number = input.nextInt();
        
        if (number <= 2) {
            for (i = 1; i<=number; i++) {
                fact = fact * i;
                System.out.println("2! = 1 x 2 ");
                System.out.println("The Factorial of 2 is: "+fact);             
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

**output:**

```
<------ Factorial Calculator ------>
Enter a positive integer: 2
The Factorial of 2 is: 1
The Factorial of 2 is: 2
```

Comment: You have your `println` call inside the `for` loop, so it prints the message every time the multiplication is performed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your print statement out of the loop.

```
if (number <= 2) {
     for (i = 1; i<=number; i++) {
          fact = fact * i;
     }
     System.out.println("The Factorial of 2 is: "+fact);             
}
```

But you may want to allow larger values than just `2`.  And don't forget that both `0!` and `1!` are equal to `1`.

Try it like this.

```
int fact = 1; //starting point for all factorials.
if (number >= 2) {
    for (int i = 2; i <= number; i++) {
         fact = fact * i;
    }
}
System.out.println(number + "! = " + fact);
```

I think you were confusing `<= 2` vs `>= 2`.  `<= 2` would only allow values `2, 1, 0, -1, etc` to enter the loop.  What you wanted was to allow values `>= 2` or `2, 3, 4, ...`

Comment: Should i replace the `if (number <= 2)` into `if  (number <= 0)` so it could allow any positive numbers except the negative ones like -1 etc.

Comment: No.  I will update my post with an example.